# Don't have drop down menu in windows explorer favourites

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I noticed there is no downloads,desktop,recent places in windows explorer links folder now when i open c:/user/links i see the tree folders in it but when i open win explorer i dont see those under favourites menu no drop down icon please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the navigation pane under Organize > Layout > Navigation Pane[image]

Then the navigation pane should appear like this: 
[image]

Comment: all of my documents,photos,favourites are shown when i click favourites there is not dropdown menu downloads etc are not shown and  navigation oane in checked

Comment: Right click on favourites, select "Restore Favourites Links" and let us know what the result is